# Why does my React Vite app with Jointjs fail to load data in production?

Tags: reactjs, vite, production-environment, jointjs

React vitejs app using jointjs failed to load data on production mode.

I have created a reactjs vitejs app using jointjs which works fine in the development mode. Once I swtich it to production mode the app does not response. It says failed to laod data.

Github link https://github.com/KaziMinhaj/jedan-app

[Console log error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0ZUm.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just cloned your repo and ran it in production using `npm run build` and `npm run preview`, and everything is working fine for me. I don't have any errors in the console (Maybe, you have made some updates).

Just as a sidenote, in `App.jsx`, you can import the `joint.css` too. This will fix your grid, and a few other CSS related things.

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import * as joint from 'jointjs';
import 'jointjs/dist/joint.css';
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it and updated the latest codes into the github. Now its working fine. Thanks for your kind effort.